# how to fix 'subraction using jquery'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to do calculation using jQuery

While subtraction,  its always subtracting from the last element

```js
 
     $(".add").click(function(){
        $(".sub").val((parseFloat($("#a").val()) - parseFloat($("#paid").val())));
      });
      $(".add").click(function(){
        $(".sub").val((parseFloat($("#b").val()) - parseFloat($("#paid").val())));
      });
      
           $(".add").click(function(){
        $(".sub").val((parseFloat($("#c").val()) - parseFloat($("#paid").val())));
      });
      
            $(".add").click(function(){
        $(".sub").val((parseFloat($("#d").val()) - parseFloat($("#paid").val())));
      });
```

```html
 


<form name="myform">
      <input type="button" id="a" value="50">
        <input type="button" id="b" value="100">
        <input type="button" id="c" value="500">
        <input type="button" id="d" value="2000">
  
      
    </form>
 <td><input type="text" name="paid" class="text" id="paid" value="10"/></td>

 <td>   <input type="button" value = "Calculate" class="add" id="add"></td>
 
       <td><input type="text" class="sub"></td>
```

when i subtract 10 from 50, it should display 40. but its showing 1990

Comment: What you want to acheive? If you are wirting multiple click handlers for a button, it will take the last one only.

Comment: then how to handle this. if i select a particular button, ex- if i subtract 10 from 50, it should show 40, if from 100 it should be 90 like that

Comment: Why would you edit this to remove jquery from the snippet? You just make it so that no one can run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code all the 4 functions are defined inside the add function. When calculate is clicked all functions run one by one and always the value of the ending function is selected. Always subtraction from 2000 takes place due to that always 1990 was the output.

```js
var a;
$('form input').click(function(){a=$(this).val()});
$(".add").click(function(){

        $(".sub").val((parseFloat(a)) - parseFloat($("#paid").val()));
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform">
      <input type="button" id="a" value="50">
        <input type="button" id="b" value="100">
        <input type="button" id="c" value="500">
        <input type="button" id="d" value="2000">
  
      
    </form>
 <td><input type="text" name="paid" class="text" id="paid" value="10"/></td>

 <td>   <input type="button" value = "Calculate" class="add" id="add"></td>
 
       <td><input type="text" class="sub"/></td>
```

Comment: Its working. Thank you very much @Ashay Mandwarya superb

Answer (score 0):

This will help :)

```js
var setVal = 0;
$(".add").click(function() {
  console.log("clicked", setVal);
  $(".sub").val(setVal - parseFloat($("#paid").val()));
  setVal = 0;
});

$("form input").click(function() {
  setVal = 0;
  setVal = this.value;
  console.log("setVal--", setVal)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="myform">
  <input type="button" id="a" value="50">
  <input type="button" id="b" value="100">
  <input type="button" id="c" value="500">
  <input type="button" id="d" value="2000">


</form>
<td><input type="text" name="paid" class="text" id="paid" value="10" /></td>

<td> <input type="button" value="Calculate" class="add" id="add"></td>

<td><input type="text" class="sub"></td>
```

Comment: Thank You Priyanshi